# Problem w/ isset($_REQUEST['form_submitted'])

Tags: php, mysqli, request

I have a isset($_REQUEST['form_submitted'])
with these 4 entries (among other) in the form:

```
 <div class="formLeft">
                    <input name="comic" type="checkbox" id="comic" value="1" <?php if (isset($auswahl)){if($dbcomic =='1'){ echo "checked";}} ?> />
                  </div>
                  <div class="formLeft">
                    <input name="comic" type="checkbox" id="comic" value="0" <?php if (isset($auswahl)){if($dbcomic =='0'){ echo "disabled";}} ?> />
                  </div>
                  <div class="formLeft">
                    <input name="onoff" type="checkbox" id="onoff" value="0" <?php if (isset($auswahl)){if($dbonoff =='0'){ echo "disabled";}} ?> />
                  </div>
                  <div class="formLeft">
                    <input name="onoff" type="checkbox" id="onoff" value="1" <?php if (isset($auswahl)){if($dbonoff =='1'){ echo "checked";}} ?> />
                  </div>
```

$auswahl is called before here:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT  * from aktuelles where id = '$auswahl'");
        while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $dbonoff = $zeile['onoff'];
                $dbcomic = $zeile['comic']; ... }
```

If the form is sent it uses:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$submit = $_POST['submit'];}
if(isset($_REQUEST['auswahl'])){$auswahl = $_REQUEST['auswahl'];}
```

and

```
if ($submit == 'aktualisieren'){
        if (isset($_REQUEST['form_submitted'])) {
...
    if(!empty($img)){$img = $img;} else {$img = $dbimg;}
    mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE aktuelles set title = '$title',...,  ablaufdatum = '$ablaufdatum', onoff = '$onoff', comic = '$comic' where id = $id");

}
```

It mainly works, but if just $dbonoff is checked and $dbcomic is disabled and not checked or the other way, I can not just disable $dbonoff as well, it turns into a white error.
It works as soon I turn also $dbcomic as is checked or the other way.
There must be an action on both sides.

Don't know how to solve this problem.

help for my problem and acknowledge...

Comment: When you say "a white error", do you mean the page fails to render and is plain white? If so, you need to find out where your error logs, or read about the "display_errors" setting, to find out what the actual error is. If you can't understand the error after reading the message and searching for related information, come back and post *the exact error message* and *the exact code that causes it*, and someone might be able to explain it to you.

Comment: yes, page is plain white.... I have to go back a step with the browser and still back on my active side.
My server hostEurope isn't good with logs, nearly no debug infos....

Comment: You have duplicated names in your form

Comment: If I give the the second form for comic the name = bcomic with Id = bcomic, and do it the way for the fourth (onoff) it doesn't change anything.
It works as far as I submit something in the form for comic & onoff but not just in one.

Comment: found the log at least:
Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'onoff' at row 1 in /is/htdocs/...aktuelles.php:195\nStack trace:\n#0 /is/htdocs/... aktuelles.php(195): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'UPDATE aktuelle...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in... aktuelles.php on line 195

Line 195 you see above as the last line, I posted as code.

Comment: forgot to say:
If use jast a pair of two of them in the form, I mean for example just both for onoff.... no problem at all.

Comment: use prepared statements and this error will go away

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: thanks, for guiding me to an Answer befor on this platform. That didn't gave me the answer for my question, but in one way it let me see where my problem was.
I found the answer for my problem here:
https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1127/php-mysql-syntax-error-insert-empty-values-not-assigned-null
And in my case I had to use:
if ($onoff == "") { $onoff = '0'; }
because onoff needs a "0" or "1" (for active) in my table field.

Also not needed anymore: the two checkboxes for comic and onoff.

But anyhow: I see I have to learn prepared statements in the near future.